# How do you return relational data from the yii2 REST API from a custom action?

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I can't for the life of me figure out how to return relational data from the REST API from a custom action. For the default actions it is as easy as using the expand parameter in the request but I can't figure out how to do it for custom actions. I have tried many ways, here is the latest:

```
public function actionSearchbycity($city)
{
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => School::find()->where(['city' => $city])->with('subjects')
    ]);
}
```

In the above example, as with all the other things I have tried this, only the School object is returned. I need the subject models as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: It does work. Forgive me for taking awhile to say so but I have been trying to figure out what I had wrong before so I could share it. I went over the process many times but I am not sure what I had wrong before. My apologies.

Comment: the above one you used doesn't work for me. As you have commented, I tried but it didn't work. However I get relational data as per my answer posted below. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function actionSearchbycity($city)
    {
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => School::find()->where(['city' => $city])->joinWith('subjects', false)
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you overwrite the `actions()` and `verbs()` methods in your controller you can tell it to use a custom 'Action' model that you create.

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'index' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
        ],
        'searchByCity' => [
            'class' => 'app\models\actions\SearchByCityAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
        ],
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
        ],
    ];
}

protected function verbs()
{
    return [
        'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'searchByCity' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
    ];
}
```

Then you can create the `SearchByCityAction` by extending
`yii\rest\Action`

It might be easier to start with a copy of `yii\rest\IndexAction`.

As long as you have the `subjects` relation setup in the `School` model and you've overwritten the `extraFields()` or `fields()` method to include the relation in the array response it should return that data when you call your api.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the result based on custom relation, you can do like

```
public function actionSearchbycity($city)
{
    $q = new yii\db\Query;
    $query = $q->select('school.*, subject.*')
        ->from('school, subject')
        ->where('school.id = subject.school_id');
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);
}
```

Here I assumed that **school** and **subject** are two tables in your db & **subject** table has a **column** named `school_id` which is **index** key whose parent is `school.id`.
By doing so, you can retrieve all the columns of both the tables as per the relation between them specified in `where()`. And it can be applied as per your custom requirement and to all tables in your db.

Hope it helps someone looking for same.